# how to merge 3 datatables?

Tags: c#, datatable, merge

I have 3 `DataTables` like this :

```
1/12   6
1/3    9
1/5    7
```

and

```
1/12   0.5
1/3    0.7
1/5    0.6
```

and

```
1/12   50
1/3    7
1/4    6
1/5    10
```

I want to merge them in order to have only one table with 4 rows, I will take the date of the first table so as a result we will have :

```
1/12   6    0.5   50
1/3    9    0.7   7
1/5    7    0.6   10
```

The row belongs to the third table with the date 1/4 does not appears because first table don't a record with this date.

it tried something like this :

```
      DataTable MergedTable = new DataTable();
      MergedTable.Columns.Add(Var.GlobalVar.Date,typeof(string));
      MergedTable.Columns.Add(Var.GlobalVar.a_part, typeof(double));
      var DateMarket = from p in AlphaTable.AsEnumerable()
                       join q in SectorTable.AsEnumerable() on p.Field<string>(Var.GlobalVar.Date) equals q.Field<string>(Var.GlobalVar.Date) into UP
                       from q in UP.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       where p.Field<string>(Var.GlobalVar.Date) != null 
                       select MergedTable.Rows.Add(q.Field<string>(Var.GlobalVar.Date), p.Field<Double>(Var.GlobalVar.a_part));
      MergedTable = DateMarket.CopyToDataTable();
```

but I don't know how I can join more than 2 `DataTables`.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean, "merge"?  Join?  Create new table?  Select into a list of objects?

Comment: Have you tried  `datatable1.Merge(datatable2)` check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx

Comment: So long as their are no unique key collisions between the databases, it should be fairly trivial.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326080/en-us